Outlook 365: Display full email address of recipients mails are sent to
Similar to this question here
Outlook 365: Display full email address of senders and recipients within organization
I also want the sent items in my outbox to show the full mailaddress of the recipients i sent
mails to.
Is there a way to get a collum that handles this?

I find that the Outbox folder does not support creating new columns, and you may have to use its default column to display recipients.

Hope it helps!

If the answer is helpful, please click "Accept Answer" and kindly upvote it. If you have extra questions about this answer, please click "Comment".
